# bash redirect: how to open file with O_CLOEXEC to prevent commands from inheriting the fd

Tags: bash

Bash redirections don't allow specifying the O_CLOEXEC flag when open() is called to open the file, but sometimes we need it. Example:

```
{
    flock -x 9
    ./do_some_work
    ./do_some_more_work
} 9< lock
```

`do_some_work` will inherit fd 9. If `do_some_work` unlocks fd 9, the lock will be released too soon.

---

KamiCuk's solution from the comments:

```
{
    flock -x 9
    {
         do_work1
         do_work2
    } 9<&-
} 9< lock
```

Comment: sooo just `./do_some_work <&9-`? Is this XY question? Why not ask "how not to inherit file descriptor"?

Comment: @KamilCuk a good solution. but if the script is very long. do we need close for every command ?

Comment: You can do `{ .... } <&9-`. Still, you asked about `O_CLOEXEC` flag....

Comment: @KamilCuk: `<&9-`  moves FD 9 to FD 0. The correct syntax for closing an FD is `9<&-` ([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to open file with O_CLOEXEC flag

It's not possible. You have to write a small Bash built-in that will open the file descriptor. I would imagine:

```
cloexec 9 file
flock -x 9
stuff
exec 9<&-
```

> to prevent command inherit the fd

To prevent a command from inheriting a file descriptor, close it.

```
command 9<&-
```

Comment: how to write a bash built-in

Comment: https://blog.dario-hamidi.de/a/build-a-bash-builtin looks ok https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582361/how-to-build-loadable-builtins-for-bash etc. use google

Comment: Look at the bash source and do the same thing existing built-in commands are doing.